# Please remove [mapview] -> [android-mapview] synonym

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I've been cleaning up a lot of [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) questions that bear the [android-mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-mapview) tag, where the authors clearly intended the [mkmapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mkmapview) tag.

Can we please remove the [mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapview) -> [android-mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-mapview) synonym? It's obviously a source of incorrectly tagged questions.

Comment: I posted this over a year ago and new iOS map view questions are still getting incorrectly tagged. Why should "mapview" map to one platform vs another?

Comment: FYI: This question was assigned to me in the [general effort](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165597/trogdor) of [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) to clean up old burnation/synonym requests, I have posted an answer and indicated the same to mods, lets hope for the best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, remove it.

Personally I have never liked in general these tag's that try to combinate multiple tags in 1.

[java-c++-performance-optimization-branch-prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-c%2b%2b-performance-optimization-branch-prediction)

[MapView](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) is a class in Google APIs for Android and this was probably the reason for it to be mapped to [android-mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-mapview), however as you have pointed out this direct mapping creates confusion in users since it's also used in other context as [r-spatial/mapview](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview), [mkmapview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview), [ArcGIS API for JavaScript](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html).

conclusion [mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapview) does not have

> exactly the same meaning as some other tag

<sup>From [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work)</sup>

since it's meaning will depend on context, I could be referring to the MapView class in ArcGIS API for javascript.

If the [mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapview) surface after this removal, I suggest that we add in [tag-excerpts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts), information about the other main tags currently used:

> If you are referring to android please use [android-mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-mapview), for iOS please use the [mkmapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mkmapview) tag